# Is there any way to index kafka outputs in Apache solr?

Tags: solr, apache-kafka

I'm new to Apache solr and I want to index data from kafka into solr. Can anyone give simple example of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get started on this would probably be to use Kafka Connect.
Connect is part of the apache Kafka package, so should already be installed on your Kakfa node(s). Please refer to the [quickstart](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html) for a brief introduction on how to run connect.

For writing data to Solr there are two connectors that you could try:

https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr

https://github.com/MSurendra/kafka-connect-solr

While I don't have any experience with either of them, I'd probably try Jeremy's first based on latest commit and the fact that he works for Confluent.